# Yosemite + Netbeans 8.0.2 + XDebug + PHP + Chrome = Looping

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug, osx-yosemite

When i put a breakpoint in a line on Netbeans 8.0.2 and run the project with Chrome, the execution will stop on this breakpoint, but Chrome keeps requesting the page again and again, so when i hit Continue in Netbeans, the execution will stop in the same breakpoint again.

The 'Network' tab on Chrome Developer Tools show one request per second and while i don't stop the debug in Netbeans, it will request the same page again and again forever ! If this request is about an database insertion, for instance, multiple inserts will be generated.

Does anyone know what is wrong here ? XDebug is useless this way.

Thanks

Comment: Chrome doesn't repeat requests except in cases of network connectivity failure. A stopped-by-debugger server won't cause that. There must be **something client-side, something in JS** that's repeating requests, but you'll need to show us what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there any place in Developer Tools where i can find some clue about what is causing the issue ?

Comment: In the Network tab, the Initiator column will show you a stack trace. In the Sources tab, you can set an XHR Breakpoint to break when the request is made (if it's an XHR request as opposed to, like, loading an image or going to a new page).

Comment: Thank you for the hint, the problem was in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my code, there was a Javascript function looping the requests. Thanks everybody for the hints.